# How to add field to Rails model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a model `Person` and based on a condition I'd like to add a field to it based on a condition.

That is, I'd need an `applied` field if the condition in the controller is met.

I did `@person.applied = true` before the method returns, and if I do `puts @person.applied`, `true` is logged, as expected. However, if I do `puts @person`, the `applied` field is not listed, while all the others (stored in the database) are.

I also have `attr_accessor :applied` in the model.

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT** (snippets)

```
 # people_controller.rb
 def show
    if @application
      @person.applied = true
    end

    puts @person.applied # logs true
    puts @person # applied is not included still

    render json: @person
```

```
 # person.rb

 class Person < ApplicationRecord
   attr_accessor :applied
 end
```

Comment: Please edit your question. Can you add code snippets?

Comment: Are you actually wanting to dynamically add a column to the database, or just an attribute to the class?

Comment: @JesusAlfonsoPintoDelgado just did!

Comment: @lurker the latter - I just need a field present in the JSON that is returned

Answer (score 4, accepted):

make this:

```
# person.rb

 class Person < ApplicationRecord
   attribute :applied
 end
```

```
 # people_controller.rb
 def show
    if @application
      @person.applied = true
    end

    p @person.applied # logs true
    p @person # applied is not included still

    render json: @person
    # rest of your code
```

this works fine with rails 6 and sqlite3

Please note that this is a virtual attribute. you have to set it in the  controller actions that you want to use it because it does not persist in the database.

Comment: you can even set the default option for an attribute and its type. `attribute :applied, :boolean, default: false` more on ActiveModel::Attributes: https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/activemodel/ActiveModel/Attributes